# FAILED Error reading manifest file: yaml: line 3: did not find expected key

Tags: cloud-foundry

FAILED
Error reading manifest file:
yaml: line 3: did not find expected key

```
---
applications:
- name: Ragu-psdonationwebservice
 memory: 128MB
 instrances: 1 
command: node ./bin/www
services:
- mymongo
```

Comment: FAILED
Error reading manifest file:
yaml: line 3: did not find expected key

---
applications:
- name: Ragu-psdonationwebservice
 memory: 128MB
 instrances: 1 
command: node ./bin/www
services:
- mymongo

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.  Try this:

```
---
applications:
- name: Ragu-psdonationwebservice
 memory: 128MB
 instances: 1 
command: node ./bin/www
services:
- mymongo
```